# Route traffic from route53 to instances in private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have instances in private subnet connected to a load balancer. NAT gateway is available in public subnet (to provide internet to private subnet). How can we route traffic from route53 to instance in private subnet.

Answer (score 2):

You have to setup **application or network load balancers in a public subnet**. Then you point your Route53 to your LB, which will in turn direct traffic to your instances in the private subnets.